# Getting queue where task came from

Tags: python, celery

I have a Celery application with 2 queues in which tasks of a given class (say, MyTask) are consumed round-robin. Some instances of MyTask are routed to the first queue, while other instances go to the second one.

Sometimes, a task needs to instantiate another object of MyTask and invoke `apply_async` again. Plus, the new task MUST be routed to the same queue as the one that is invoking it.

Problem is, I couldn't find in Celery's docs a way to get the queue from which the first task was consumed. Is there a straightforward, clean way of doing this?

Comment: Have you checked `delivery_info` on [Task context](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context)?

Comment: Perfect! It's incredible that this is not mentioned on the queues section of the docs. Please post this as an answer so I can choose it :)

Comment: ha ha ha :) ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `delivery_info` on [Task context](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context).